# Python clickhouse_driver through ssh connection error

Tags: python, ssh, ssh-tunnel, clickhouse

struggling for a week already with my issue, hope you'll be able to explain to me what is wrong here.

I'm trying to connect Clickhouse DB I have on the remote server, which is on the absolutely default settings. So I'm connecting to a remote server and creating a tunnel on my machine.

```
import sshtunnel as sshtunnel
from clickhouse_driver import connect

server = sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('host', 22),
    ssh_username='username',
    ssh_pkey="username.openssh",
    ssh_private_key_password="password",
    remote_bind_address=('localhost', 8123),
    local_bind_address=('localhost', 555)
)

server.start()
conn = connect(host='localhost', port=555, database='ertb')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SHOW TABLES')
cursor.fetchall()
server.stop()
```

and I receive this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/alerts/ssh_coonection.py", line 42, in <module>
    cursor.execute('SHOW TABLES')
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\alerts\venv\lib\site-packages\clickhouse_driver\dbapi\cursor.py", line 102, in execute
    **execute_kwargs
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\alerts\venv\lib\site-packages\clickhouse_driver\client.py", line 205, in execute
    self.connection.force_connect()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\alerts\venv\lib\site-packages\clickhouse_driver\connection.py", line 180, in force_connect
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\alerts\venv\lib\site-packages\clickhouse_driver\connection.py", line 256, in connect
    return self._init_connection(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\alerts\venv\lib\site-packages\clickhouse_driver\connection.py", line 237, in _init_connection
    self.send_hello()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\alerts\venv\lib\site-packages\clickhouse_driver\connection.py", line 325, in send_hello
    write_binary_str(self.user, self.fout)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\alerts\venv\lib\site-packages\clickhouse_driver\writer.py", line 19, in write_binary_str
    text = text.encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I really tried to understand from where this NoneType object appears, but a bit stuck in code.

Comment: but mymarilyn/clickhouse-driver uses tcp protocol on port 9000 not http(8123)

Comment: Thank you, I've used 9000 port and clickhouse_driver Client so everything started to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

- is not passed *user* and *password* that leads to the error *'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'*
- used the wrong port to access to CH ([clickhouse-driver](https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) is designed to communicate with ClickHouse server over [native protocol (TCP)](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/tcp/) that by default use port 9000 for non-secure communication (see [Issue connecting to Dockerized Clickhouse Server with Python driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61298575/303298) for details))

```py
import sshtunnel as sshtunnel
from clickhouse_driver import connect

with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('localhost', 22),
    ssh_username="root",
    ssh_password="root",
    remote_bind_address=('localhost', 9000)) as server:

    local_port = server.local_bind_port
    print(local_port)

    conn = connect(f'clickhouse://default:@localhost:{local_port}/ertb')
    #conn = connect(host='localhost', port=local_port, database='ertb', user='default', password='')

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SHOW TABLES')
    print(cursor.fetchall())
```